What is the Theistic response for Necessary being has conscious or not?
In the Argument of Contingency (Leibniz and Aquinas Cosmological Argument) and Ontological Argument, it is argued that necessary being exists and they claim Necessary being is God. My question is Why would it be God, why necessary being has to be conscious, why can't something like necessary system(a being which is capable of causing things, but does not have mind) be a necessary being?
Necessary Being: Something that exists eternally, it's explanation of existance does not depend on anything but itself, has to exists, exists in all possible worlds, impossible to not exists.

This question is similar to your previous question: Can something other than God be necessary being(other than abstract objects), like non-physical metaphysically systems?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

From previous question, a chat discussion, and the general ontological argument tag. Just linking since the chat might be helpful for context on this question, and the tag has questions that are almost certainly similar

I will say, @JoWehler, I think one key difference between this question and the previous one is that this one asks specifically for the theistic response, while the previous one asked "can arguments about necessity be applied to non-God things", which means the answer can simply be "arguments about necessity fail or produce nonsensical results". I think "How would someone who accepts the prime-mover argument as convincing proof of a God respond to the idea that the prime-mover need not be conscious?" requires different answers than the previous question got.

@JoWehler yes you are right, I just wanted to get more answers because I don't yhink it was enough sir.

@Kaia thank you for correcting me preciate it.

This question as pointed out by some commentators is somewhat ambiguous.
From what I'm aware Aquinas' Cosmological Argument is meant to get around the Infinite Regression paradox - while still arguing in favor of God's existence. More on that later.
It is my understanding, that the theistic proposal of a necessary being is because humanity understands little about the nature of the universe - and how the many theories of causation may or may not be applicable.
Overview of Big Bang Cosmology.
This misconception stems from the idea that the universe had a beginning. It has been within the cosmological perspective for the past century or so, and only until more recent times (a few decades) that space, time, and matter began to exist. However, there has been a paradigm shift within cosmology. That is our understanding of whether or not the "Big Bang" is a sufficient explanation of the beginning of our universe has changed.
The Big Bang is not the start of the universe but rather an observation that the universe is expanding exponentially from a very hot and dense state. It was previously thought the universe expanded outward from a central point, this is not the case. The Big Bang Theory purports that space, time, and matter came into existence simultaneously, within the universe. You can think of the universe as the set of all things.
What does this have to do with a Necessary Being? (NB)
From my understanding, the concept of NB as it relates to many cosmological arguments is erroneous because theists often conflate the Big Bang Theory with the beginning of the universe. (The distinction lies between the universe being presumed as the set of all things, rather than all space, time, and matter) And because of this, cosmological arguments like the ones you've mentioned have been popularized. But it is my understanding, that the current cosmological model does not accept that time necessarily started during expansion - rather there was no t=0. We just more recently developed both the faculties (through evolution) and the technology to start capturing this data. Again, the jury is still out on the ontology of some metaphysical concepts like space and time. And there are conflicting hypotheses within the scientific community so take this with a grain of salt. I will say it'd be very odd for cosmologists and theoretical physicists to commit themselves fully to one explanation unless it solves every single problem. And to my knowledge that answer does not exist yet.
Brief Socratic analysis:
The universe exists.

Q1: Did it begin to exist? Or is it eternal?

A1: The jury is out on either.

Q2: If we granted that the universe began to exist the theist ponders whether it must've been created.

A2: (This runs parallel to Paley's watchmaker analogy). Where because people design watches (or more generally, things), it may be true that the universe itself has a designer. However, I'd be careful of how much credence you give Paley's analogy; since we can see watchmakers design watches - we do not see, nor do we know of a designer for the universe.

Q&A3: When we grant that the universe is eternal, that it has always existed - is when theists get squirmy. They may ask things like. "Where does God fit into this equation?" or, "Surely God can't exist co-eternally alongside the universe." Primarily because the Abrahamic conception of God (along with many other mono/poly-theistic interpretations) believes that God(s) created the universe. And so there naturally is an attempt at finding a theory (cosmological, et al.) that is compatible with the respective theistic conception of God.


To answer your question about a conscious NB.
Whether God would have to be conscious to create space time and matter is a difficult question to answer.
If for example, we base our definition of consciousness on Nagel's:

"According to Nagel, a being is conscious just if there is “something that it is like” to be that creature, i.e., some subjective way the world seems or appears from the creature's mental or experiential point of view." - Read here

Then one might say, that to be conscious is just to experience. If this is the case - then you might ask yourself if will is contingent on consciousness.
If we simply define will as an agent's ability to make decisions, then I'd argue consciousness (under Nagel's view) may not be a requirement to act at all.
We can conceptualize an agent that has no experience nor capacity for it, but which follows a set of instructions (like a computer program) that is volitional. We can also conceive of a possible world in which this program and the laws or "rules" that govern it, exist co-eternally. So it may not be necessary for an agent to be conscious (to be able to experience) in order to both have and execute will, (e.g. creating space, time, and matter.)
This depends on the theory of causation being used (e.g if God exists outside of causation what then?), some would argue that an eternal universe would lead to an infinite regression of causes, and therefore lack explanatory power - attempting to short-circuit this with God as the answer doesn't solve the problem. It merely shifts focus on the ontology of God's existence (and the nature of causality) and puts into question whether a NB is even necessary at all.

Preciate it. Thank you
